# Clojure, defn, defn-, public/private, defaults

Tags: clojure

- `defn` = public
- `defn-` = private

Perhaps I have bad Clojure coding style -- but I find that most functions I write in Clojure are small helper functions that I do not want to expose.

Is there some configuration option, where:

- `defn` = private by default,
- and to make something public, I have to do `defn+`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. There is not.

An alternative approach which might or might not work for you is to declare a `foo.bar.internal` namespace containing all the private helpers which is used by your `foo.bar` namespace. This has advantages over private function declarations when you want to use private functions in macro expansions.

Comment: Not just that there isn't, it would really mess with the mind of any other Clojurian looking at such code. I would discourage it even if it were doable.

Answer (score 6):

If the "helper functions" are very likely to be used once, you could choose to make them locals of your bigger functions, or write them as anonymous functions. See `letfn`: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/letfn and http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/fn.

I hardly ever use `letfn` myself.

Comment: I don't think the size of these helper functions matters. If they're used more than once, they really should be abstracted for dryer code. I can't really see a reason for making them local/anonymous unless they're only used once locally.

Comment: This is true. I will adapt the answer.

Comment: I tried to use `letfn` for my helpers, but it made my code too messy. So, after a short time I switched back to `defn-`.

Answer (score 6):

The beauty of Clojure being a Lisp, is that you can build and adapt the language to suit your needs.  I highly recommend you read [On Lisp, by Paul Graham](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html).  He now gives his book away for free.

Regarding your suggestion of defn+ vs defn vs defn-.  This sound to me like a good case for writing your own Macro.  `defn` is a function and `defn-` is a macro.  You can simply redefine them as you wish, or wrap them in your own.

Here follows a suggestion to implementation, based mainly on Clojure's own implementation - including a simple utility, and a test.

```
(defmacro defn+
    "same as Clojure's defn, yielding public def"
    [name & decls]
    (list* `defn (with-meta name (assoc (meta name) :public true)) decls))

(defmacro defn
    "same as Clojure's defn-, yielding non-public def"
    [name & decls]
    (list* `defn (with-meta name (assoc (meta name) :private true)) decls))

(defn mac1
    "same as `macroexpand-1`"
    [form]
    (. clojure.lang.Compiler (macroexpand1 form)))

(let [  ex1 (mac1 '(defn f1 [] (println "Hello me.")))
        ex2 (mac1 '(defn+ f2 [] (println "Hello World!"))) ]
    (defn f1 [] (println "Hello me."))
    (defn+ f2 [] (println "Hello World!"))
    (prn ex1) (prn (meta #'f1)) (f1)
    (prn ex2) (prn (meta #'f2)) (f2) )
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated by @kotarak, there is no way (as far as I know) to do that, nor is it desirable.

Here is why I dislike `defn-` :

I found out that when using various Clojure libraries I sometimes need to slightly modify one function to better suit my particular needs.
It is often something quite small, and that makes sense only in my particular case. Often this is just a char or two.

But when this function reuses internal private functions, it makes it harder to modify. I have to copy-paste all those private functions.

I understand that this is a way for the programmer to say that "this might change without notice".

Regardless, I would like the opposite convention :

- always use `defn`, which makes everything public
- use `defn+` (that doesn't exist yet) to specify to the programmer which functions are part of the public API that he is supposed to use. `defn+` should be no different from `defn`otherwise.

Also please note that it is possible to [access private functions](http://christophermaier.name/blog/2011/04/30/not-so-private-clojure-functions) anyway :

```
;; in namespace user
user> (defn- secret []
        "TOP SECRET")

;; from another namespace
(#'user/secret) ;;=> "TOP SECRET"
```

Comment: From my experience with Ruby which allows unrestricted access to everything (just use #send for private methods). It ends up being a huge mess and less experienced developers tend to abuse this "freedom" by doing really bad things.

Comment: After working on a big clojure codebase, I actually found some value for the private `defn-` case. I have yet to try using `defn+`.

Comment: Exactly. If I make a mistake modifying someone else's function, it's my fault. As a programmer, blocking me from modifying internals is an insult. Everything should be public. Just document any potential issues correctly and there's no need for private.

Comment: @Rebs wow, I have a completely opposite opinion. APIs are supposed to shield the user from their internal complexity. I'm probably influenced by my strong object oriented background but I really don't see how freely modifying the internals of a library can be a good idea. Ever.

Comment: @Dici There are times you need to add to or modify the internals of other peoples code. Nothing is worse than finding a class you need to extend but everything is protected. You as a programmer cannot think of everything possible. Mark the internals as "please don't touch" Python style (_var, _method), but don't stop me. The more barriers in place, the more verbose my code has to be in order to work in / around those barriers. Write APIs that are layers, not barriers. Add value, don't remove it. Do you really not trust other programmers? Why code a paranoid library?

Comment: I don't know, many languages implement this sort of private scope and it never bothered me when working with them. I think it's safer, and cleaner. Library writers are most of the time better at what they do than library users.